# React JS - Call same API endpoint for each table row until response contains certain criteria

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous

I have an application which needs to call the same endpoint but with a different parameter for each row of a table.

My app looks like this thus far:

[image: Table Data]

This does the following:

When the Generate Journey button is clicked, it will POST a bunch of data to a server and get a response as follows:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "customerId": "db7dab81-0b33-41d3-a4a9-861a45c282b5",
  "serviceId": "ac1f0b6f-593e-4377-9697-d8dbe06c6309",
  "numberOfJourneys": 3,
  "generationStatus": "QUEUED",
}
```

Notice the `QUEUED` status. The backend will generate the journeys and once it has completed the status will be changed to `COMPLETED`.

Once the journey has been created, we can then emulate it by clicking the emulate button, which will then in turn, post some data to another API and emulate a journey.

Now my problem is this:

What is the best way to achieve this functionality? As I am going to have to repeatedly call the endpoint to check if the status is `COMPLETED` before I can emulate the journey, for each table row.

I do not currently have a solution for this as of yet but thinking something along the lines of this:

```
getJourneyEmulations() {
    let promise;
    promise = journeyCreationStatus();

    if (!promise) {
        return;
    }

    this.setState({
        isLoading: true
    });

    promise.then(response => {
        const generationStatus = this.state.generationStatus;
        this.setState({
            generationStatus: generationStatus,
            isLoading: false
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false
        });
        console.log(error);
    })
}
```

Then call it with a timer in `componentDidMount` like:

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.getRouteGenerations();
    this.timer = setInterval(()=> this.getJourneyEmulations(), 10000)
}
```

However, i do not think this will work as i need to call this for each table row.

If more explanation is needed please leave a comment and i will try to explain.

Thanks

Comment: If you own or can modify the server, take a look at [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Websockets_API), with this you can notify you client when the `QUEUE` is `COMPLETE`

Answer (score 0):

So there's multiple options with this type of problem, such as long polling or websockets but I will assume you don't have access to the server, so the only option is to repeatedly call the server.

Also, I guess you would send one POST at the beginning, and then the endpoint (or some other endpoint) would give you the information of weather the generationStatus is completed or not via a GET.

The code for fetching multiple times until success may look like this one :

```js
const url = 'your/api/url/';
const INTERVAL_MS = 5000;

function delay() {
  return new Promise(resolve => setInterval(resolve, INTERVAL_MS))
}

function isCompleted(data) {
  return data.generationStatus === 'COMPLETED'
}

function postJourney(data) {
  return fetch(
    url,
    {
      method:'POST',
      body:JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
}

function checkStatusUntilCompleted() {
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
    if (!isCompleted(json)) {
      // we retry after some delay if it was not completed
      return delay().then(checkStatusUntilCompleted)
    }
    else {
      return Promise.resolve(json)
    }
  })
}

function postJourneyAndCheckUntilCompleted(rowData) {
  postJourney(rowData)
    .then(json => {
    if (!isCompleted(json)) {
      return delay().then(checkStatusUntilCompleted)
    }
    else {
      return Promise.resolve(json)
    }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // do stuff, it is completed now
  })
}
```

Also, you may want to handle HTTP errors, CSRF Token, and/or use a custom fetch wrapper.

Then you would call postJourney from the render function in the following way :

```js
rowDatas.map((rowData) => (
   <TableRow key={rowData.key}>
      <Cell>{rowData.customerId}</Cell>
      /* ... */
     <Cell><Button onClick={() => postJourneyAndCheckUntilCompleted(rowData)}>Generate Journey</Button></Cell>
   </TableRow>
)
```

Cheers

Comment: Albeit this is good code for polling, the OP is primarily asking how to create and manage state change polling requests for each row in the Journey table, the OP demonstrates code for handling ONE polling request in the question already.

Comment: clearInterval is never called in the OP code so it will keep running. Also using it for multiple rows is pretty straight forward, just call postJourney with the data of the row of the clicked button.

Comment: Then adjust your answer to demonstrate managing multiple rows, especially if pretty straight forward, the OP is directly asking for that

Comment: I do not have access to the server but one of my colleagues does. Would it be easier to implement a web sockets solution?

Comment: This does not really answer my question fully. I need to do this for multiple rows of a table, not just one.

Comment: It depends of the technology. If you're using Django as backend for example, it may require to change a bit the architecture (WSGI -> ASGI, possibly a Redis server to share events accross multiple clients). If you're using Node, not as complicated but requires a bit of setup.

Comment: When you click on a 'Generate Journey' it generates only one journey right ? I updated the answer.

Comment: Yes it generates one journey. Thanks for the updated solution